# Do If statements stop code after it being executed?

Tags: javascript

I have an order form script with a function in which says if the job will take longer than x flash up a message. Script works fine if i leave my if statement out, but If i put it in it only executes if X variable meets the if condition, does this make sense?

My Script is...

```
if (EstimatedCoreHours >= 50000)
   {
   document.getElementById("AccountManagement").innerHTML='You have a big Job on your hands - Contact Us!';
   document.getElementById("AccountManagement").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
   }
   else
   {
   document.getElementById("AccountManagement").innerHTML=''; 
   document.getElementById("ContBtn").style.display="";
   }

   if (EstimatedCoreHours >= 100000)
   {
   document.getElementById("LeadTimes").innerHTML='5 Business Days!';
   document.getElementById("LeadTimes").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
   }
   else if (EstimatedCoreHours >=25000)
   {
   document.getElementById("LeadTimes").innerHTML='2 Days';  
   document.getElementById("LeadTimes").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
   }
   else
   {
   document.getElementById("LeadTimes").innerHTML='Right Away'; 
   document.getElementById("LeadTimes").style.backgroundColor="yellow";  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* statements will not stop execution. Execution stops when the interpreter encounters an error in the code. Check whether the variable used inside the *if* is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a mix of ifs and else-ifs here and the indents are wrong. If EstimatedCoreHours is say 150,000 then the first two ifs will both fire. Did you mean them to be nested?

One last point, the criteria run 50,000, 100,000, 25,000. Are you deliberately testing the values out of order or is there a typo here?